Save curvilinear grid to NetCDF file using R
I am working with ROMS ocean model outputs, which have curvilinear grids. I would like to be able to save a variable (subset) from those outputs to a NetCDF file in a way that it is recognised to have a curvilinear grid when that file is accessed again (e.g. from R, with the stars package, but I may also want to use tools outside of R, e.g. gdalwarp). Is there a way to construct the NetCDF file appropriately?
Herewith an example:
## load packages
require(stars)
require(ncdf4)

## filenames & directories
filename <- "http://dap.saeon.ac.za/thredds/dodsC/SAEON.EGAGASINI/2019.Penven/DAILY_MEANS/1_12_degree/roms_avg_Y2014M11.nc.1"
outfile <- "woesII_singleDay_temp_vertlevl60.nc"

## loading curvilinear ocean model data file

## first look at the file structure
nc_open(filename) # it is a large and complex file, but we can extract a single variable slice below

Use stars::read_ncdf() to read "temp" variable, selecting all longitudes, latitudes and only a single depth layer (3rd dimension) and time-step (4th dimension), so that we end up with a variable with two dimensions
ncvar_wII <- read_ncdf(filename, var = "temp", ncsub = cbind(start = c(1, 1, 60, 1), count = c(NA, NA, 1, 1)), curvilinear = c("lon_rho", "lat_rho"), make_time = F) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  .[,,,,drop=T] # drop the (single unit) depth and time dimensions

ncvar_wII # curvilinear grid of surface temperature

# plot(ncvar_wII) # takes a few seconds

Now, how do we save that 2-D variable in a netcdf file so that it is recognised to have a curvilinear grid?!
## trying with stars package:

write_stars(ncvar_wII, outfile)

## reloading to check:
nc_open(outfile) # look at file contents
ncvar2 <- read_ncdf(outfile, var = "Band1") # fails
ncvar2 <- read_ncdf(outfile, var = "Band1", curvilinear = c("lon", "lat"), make_time = F) # fails # Specified curvilinear coordinates are not 2-dimensional.

In my limited experience and understanding, I think curvilinear grids require their coordinates to be specified as variables that consist of 2-D matrices, which is not the case in the netcdf file saved with write_stars() above.
Trying to reconstruct a similar structure to the original netcdf file using the ncdf4 package doesn't get me there either (but as with the stars package, it may be due to my lack of familiarity & skills):
## using ncdf4 package, fetch the relevant variables and dimensions and then rebuild a netcdf file:

dta <- nc_open(filename) #
lons <- ncvar_get(dta, 'lon_rho') # fetch the longitude variable (a 2-D matrix of longitudes)
lats <- ncvar_get(dta, 'lat_rho') # fetch the latitude variable (a 2-D matrix of laitudes)
lon_dim <- ncvar_get(dta, "xi_rho") # fetch the x dimension (a vector of integers with an almost-repeating sequence I haven't understood why)
lat_dim <- ncvar_get(dta, "eta_rho") # fetch the y dimension (a vector of integers with an almost-repeating sequence I haven't understood why)
temperature <- ncvar_get(dta, "temp", start = c(1,1,60,1), count = c(-1,-1,1,1)) # fetch a 2-D surface of temperature
nc_close(dta)
# fields::image.plot(temperature)

# Define dimensions
x_dim <- ncdim_def(name = "xi_rho", units = "", vals = lon_dim)
y_dim <- ncdim_def(name = "eta_rho", units = "", vals = lat_dim)

# define coordinate variables
lon_var <- ncvar_def(name = "lon_rho", units = "degrees_east", dim = list(x_dim, y_dim), missval = NA)
lat_var <- ncvar_def(name = "lat_rho", units = "degrees_north", dim = list(x_dim, y_dim), missval = NA)

# define the data variable
data_var <- ncvar_def(name = "temp", units = "C", dim = list(x_dim, y_dim), missval = NA)

# Create NetCDF file
ncfile <- nc_create(outfile, vars = list(data_var, lon_var, lat_var))

# Write data to the file
ncvar_put(ncfile, data_var, temperature)
ncvar_put(ncfile, lon_var, lons)
ncvar_put(ncfile, lat_var, lats)

# Add global attributes
ncatt_put(ncfile, 0, "title", "Surface temperature data on curvilinear grid")

# Close the file
nc_close(ncfile)

## check with ncdf4
nc_open(outfile)

I noticed in the original file the variable 'temp' has an attribute "coordinates: lat_rho lon_rho", but I don't know how to specify that in the netcdf file created (I tried a few things) and perhaps that is the relevant difference between them (with respect to the file/variable being recognised as having a curvilinear grid).
## try to load it with stars, specifying curvilinear grid as above:
ncvar2 <- read_ncdf(outfile, var = "temp", curvilinear = c("lon_rho", "lat_rho"), make_time = F)
# error: Specified curvilinear coordinate variables not found as X/Y coordinate variables.


If anyone could demonstrate how to construct the NetCDF file in the correct way so that the curvilinear grid is recognised, that would be much appreciated. I need to do this from R as I calculate some statistics over many files (timesteps) before creating the NetCDF file.

some 'solutions' presented here nc curvilinear, though you've likely seen this (these).

I had seen that one, thanks @Chris. It and some of the linked resources did help my initial understanding, although the focus seemed to be on grid rotation, which I didn't face in my case.

What you have here is a netCDF file that has data variables (like the temp array that you are interested in) with coordinate variables that are not longitude-latitude in the horizontal plane. Coordinate variables are those netCDF variables (the objects in the file) that share a name with the dimensions that the data variable uses. As per the CF Metadata Conventions (which your file does not report on), the file should then have auxiliary coordinate variables to indicate longitude and latitude for each cell in the data variable; those are lat_rho and lon_rho in the coordinates attribute. lat_rho and lon_rho are matrices of the same dimension as a slice of temp data which give the latitude and longitude for each cell in the matrix, respectively.
Unfortunately, there are no R packages (that I know off) that interpret these auxiliary coordinate variables. stars only looks at the coordinate variables, in this case xi_rho and eta_rho (which have no attributes to help us identify what their coordinates represent; from the ROMS wiki it becomes clear that this is a fractional coordinate system). The only solution is to write your own code. You'd have to interpolate lat_rho and lon_rho to find index values into the data variables for every grid location. In simple terms, for every cell in your desired output grid, find the (col, row) pair in (lon_rho, lat_rho) that is closest to the (lon, lat) on your output grid. Tedious and slow but fortunately you'll have to do this only once; you can re-use this index grid for other time or depth slices, or other data variables that use the same (xi_rho, eta_rho) grid.
Once you have done all of that, you'll find that the depth dimension is called s_rho, a sigma level for a parametric vertical coordinate with values running from (about) -1 to 0. You would need to apply a formula to compute the "altitude", the standard_name for the computed value of "ocean_s_coordinate_g1", for which you will need to use the variables listed in the formula_terms attribute of s_rho: sc_r, Cs_r, zeta, h and hc.
All of this is of a level of complexity that no R package currently  manages properly. But that may change soon (but how soon is now?, to paraphrase The Smiths). I am the developer of package ncdfCF which will fully support the CF Metadata Conventions. The package is currently very basic but work is progressing, albeit slowly. If you are interested, open an issue on GitHub with your posting and then we can discuss there and work towards a solution.

Thank you for taking the time to engage and provide an answer, Patrick. Are you suggesting that the way I load the variable with the stars R package is not handling/interpreting it correctly? In case of any interest or use, some explanation of the ROMS grid can be found here.
I'm uncertain what you mean with "You'd have to interpolate lat_rho and lon_rho to find index values into the data variables for every grid location."; if you are able to clarify or provide a simple example to demonstrate, that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Hi @jock, please see my updated answer. I suggest we move any further discussion to the GitHub issues page that is linked above.

Thanks for your effort to explain, Patrick. Glad to hear of the package you're developing. I'm not sure I have the understanding to open a meaningful issue, but will shout if I get to that point. I feel like these curvilinear grids have defeated me. I thought I was telling stars to use the auxiliary coordinate variables with argument r curvilinear = c("lon_rho", "lat_rho"). When you say I need to interpolate lat_rho and lon_rho, are you meaning to regrid onto a rectilinear grid? If so, I was achieving something (for which the outcome looked sensible) with stars::st_warp().
